# Правильная структура данных во vue.js - конструктор форм

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Делаю довольно обычный конструктор форм, но встал вопрос о структуре данных. Дано:

1. Корневой компонент. В нем есть данные о рядах (`row`).
2. Элемент `row`. Он принимает кол-во ячеек, а также содержит информацию о вложенных в него элементах `cell`.
3. Элемент `cell`. Он содержит в себе данные об инпутах, которые уже рендерятся в форму.

Корневой компонент:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <row v-for="row in rows"></row>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" :click="addRow">Добавить ряд</a>
    </div>
</template>    
<script>
    import row from './RowComponent'    
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                rows: [],    
            }
        },
        methods: {    
            addRow() {

            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Застрял с созданием структуры данных. Каждая строка не зависит от другой и, с теоретической стороны, может быть создана отдельно и хранить в себе дочерние компоненты, не сообщая через `emit` родительскому компоненту про свое изменение. Но можно ли так сделать?

По сути, мне нужно в методе `addRow()` реализовать добавление нового компонента `row`, но как я могу это сделать, не делая при этом ничего в `data` и не рендеря через `v-for` компоненты `row`?

Comment: MVVM братан! Рендер разметки дожен зависеть от данных. Метод addRow просто пушит новый элемент в массив rows. Плюс ты забыл подключить компонент. Плюс это плохая практика называть компонент отлично от файла в котором он содержится.

Comment: @Piterden да, уже прочитал про это. Вопрос даже немного по-другому поставлю: является ли ошибкой хранить данные о ячейках в компоненте `row`, а не в корневом? Или же мне нужно все данные хранить в едином хранилище (тут уже про vuex задуматься можно)?

Comment: Данные нужно хранить или в ближайшем общем родителе тех мест, где они тебе понадобятся, либо в рут-компоненте (vuex всего лишь более удобная замена второго способа)